# Interface não reconhece tipo de classe mesmo com DLL declarada

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, web-service

Criei um projeto Class Library e nele uma classe POCO. Criei uma Interface (tudo isso seguindo o livro do John Sharp). Depois criei meu WS com WCF. Bem, na interface eu declarei um método do tipo da minha classe criada na Class Library e a interface não reconheceu. Adicionei a DLL na referência do projeto e mesmo assim eu não consigo incluir no projeto. O que devo fazer?

Estou tentando de várias maneiras e sem sucesso. Já removi e adicionei a DLL, reiniciei a máquina e mesmo assim, nada. A classe está mapeada com DataContract. O código está assim:

```cs
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace SuporteTecnicoContracts
{ 
    [Table(Name="T_PDV")]
    [DataContract]
    public class TPDV
    {
        [Column]
        [DataMember]
        public int IDPdv { get; set; }
        [Column]
        [DataMember]
        public string CNPJ { get; set; }
        [Column]
        [DataMember]
        public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }
.......
```

Minha Interface

```cs
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using SuporteTecnicoContracts;

namespace SuporteTecnico.Interface
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISuporteTecnicoContract
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/")]
        TPDV getCnpjParceiro(string _cnpj); ==> Não reconhece TPDV
    }
}
```

Comment: Só esclarecendo: `TPDV` está em uma DLL e `ISuporteTecnicoContract` está no WS. O WS referencia a DLL. Certo?

Comment: Está assim: Um projeto class library(SuporteTecnicoContracts) que tem o TPDV. Uma interface que está no meu projeto principal, não no class library que tem a DLL do class library. E um svc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seguinte. Eu estava com um svc dentro de meu projeto principal. Criei um novo projeto WCF Service Application à parte. Criei e ele criou um projeto a parte, ficando minha solution com 5 projetos. Dessa forma resolveu o problema de reconhecer o tipo citado acima. Esse problema resolveu. Só não entendi porque não reconheceu quando o svc estava no mesmo projeto.